# Dependency Injection for WPF in VS2015

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015

So it appears that ASP.NET 5 is getting dependency injection out-of-the box in Visual Studio 2015.

What about WPF and dependency injection in Visual Studio 2015? Are we still reliant on 3rd party solutions when it comes to implementing MVVM with IoC in WPF?

Comment: Even with ASP.NET 5, for any real development, you will still have to rely on a 3rd party library, because the feature set of the built-in DI solution of ASP.NET is extremely limited. Some of the things that are missing IMO that would make this a real competitor to the mature OSS libraries are: batch-registration, resolving generic types, applying decorators and container diagnostics.